# jquery change opacity and height on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollto, nav

I'm currently trying to write a little js. My navigation has a gradient set as background.
I want the background to change in height and from a gradient to a flat color with 0.85 opacity (animated) when I scroll down a certain amount.

here's my js code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 600){
     $('#navigation').css({height: '92px'});
} else {
     $('#navigation').css({height: '142px'});
    }
});
```

here's the css

```
#navigation {

height: 142px;
width: 1350px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2000;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bf000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

}

hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good !!

Just create two separate class and replace your `$('#navigation').css({height: '92px'});` by `$('#navigation').addClass("flatColored");` and `$('#navigation').removeClass("flatColored");` in the 'else'.

instead of having `#navigation{ ...}` in your css, use `.gradientColored{...} .flatcolored{...}`

and in your html : `<div id="navigation" class="gradientColored">...</div>`

Override the `background` properties in the 'flatColored class.

Tested on chrome, based on your code. Works fine !