# jquery navigation color and height change on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, background-color, nav

I'm looking to change the navigation from transparent to a color on scroll. Much like this site. http://createone.com/contact-us/ I've seen posts about changing size which is great, I'll use this as well but would like to mainly go from transparent to a color. Any help would be great. I do have a little experience with jquery but haven't been able to figure it out or modify someone else's previous questions to my needs.

I saw this but wasn't able to get it to work for me. [jquery change opacity and height on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553444/jquery-change-opacity-and-height-on-scroll)

A jsfiddle demo would be great!

Thanks in advance for the help. Also I'm using Bootstrap 4 so if there's any plugins out there. I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you can check this to begin : **http://jsfiddle.net/rcAev/177/**

Here i made this function:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
 $(window).scroll (function () {
    var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (sT >= 300) {
            $('.overlay').addClass('cambio')
        }else {
            $('.overlay').removeClass('cambio')
        }
  })
})
```

I'll explain you step by step:

- First this executes the function every time you scroll the window

> $(window).scroll (function ()

- Second read the value from the top of the scroll to know how much you advance

> var sT = $(this).scrollTop();

- Third compare to the breakpoint you want , in this case i choose 300 because i want to change the nav after pass the height form the image.

  ```
  if (sT >= 300) {
          /*action you want after the 300 or more scroll*/
      }else {
          /*action you want before the 300 scroll*/
      }
  ```
- Fourth to change the transparent to color the action i apply is add a `class` with new background and different height:

  ```
  $('.overlay').addClass('cambio')
  ```

Comment: This looks great! I'm going to give it a try on my site. Thanks so much! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Perfect you can complete this with more advanced things such transitions or animations but this is the way you can begin

Comment: This is awesome! I got it to work perfectly. Is there an easy solution for making it happen over a short time so it's not so jumpy?

Comment: Of course you can use transition:all 1s; on the overlay check this http://jsfiddle.net/rcAev/24/

Comment: This is awesome thanks so much. You really helped me out a bunch.

Comment: @DaniP if the page is opened at a point after the overlay class has been added. how would you check for this and re-run the addclass needed to keep the effect?

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery you mean if you open the page already scrolled ?

Comment: @DaniP yes thats what i mean sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In this [site](http://createone.com/contact-us/), the navigation height is not actually changing. It's [fixed positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). The navigation is positioned relative to the browser window.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xeP7M/1/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="first"></div><div id="second"></div><div id="third"></div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.nav{
    position:fixed;
}
div#first{
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    background:#59071D;
}
div#second{
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    background:#735448;
}
div#third{
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    background:#F2DDB6;
}
```

Comment: Yea I understand the part about fixing the nav but they also switched from transparent to white on the nav background. Would you be able to show me how to do something like that? Thanks so much for the quick response btw.

Comment: They change class of body element according to scroll. I'll make you simple example after lunch!